# How to store multiple class's different objects inside of a vector?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

So my code I want to make a vector that takes any object that is from a derived class of "PLATFORM". 
So Platform is my base class, and I have things like books, games, tv shows, and other things. I want to put all of these inside of a single vector. It needs to be done this way, so there is no other way to go about it.

So I want a vector to contain... an object from books, an object from games, etc...
I've been reading around on forums, and I consistently see people suggesting the use of boost::any or boost::variant. I'm trying to avoid using boost at the moment.

I've seen multiple suggestions like...
doing something like

```
Book tmpBook;
tmpBook.setName("ERAGON");
//I do the above just to get a object to use


vector<Platforms*> platforms
platforms.push_back(tmpBook)
cout << platforms.at(0).getName() << endl;
```

I expected to see it print out ERAGON, but I got an error...
error: request for member 'getName' in 'platforms.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at >(0u)', which is of pointer type... And it goes on from here.

I feel like i'm missing something very crucial here, so please help!

My classes are set up simply with base class "Platform" with a getName() and setName() virtual method and a protected string name variable.

The derived classes basically just have the setName() and getName() versions for their class.

Later, I plan to add more details that further define each class with more defining features for their respective objects. like a book having a page number and such...

I've also seen the suggestion of using the sharedptr, but it seemed so complicated...

Comment: `cout << platforms.at(0)->getName() << endl;`

Comment: Thank you πάντα ῥεῖ, that was what i was missing, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
Vector<Platforms> platforms
```

I cant get that why are you using pointer in vector

Comment: _"I cant get that why are you using pointer in vector"_ Because `Platforms` is a (probably abstract) base class as stated in the question.

Comment: Sometimes it seems hard that you can't post comments from the start, but do not misuse questions for that. Earn your right to post comments.